# When a function of two random variables is Gumbel?

Tags: probability, distributions, nonparametric, gumbel-distribution

Consider two random variables $X,Y$.

Is there any example in which $X$ and $Y$ have a known parametric distribution such that $f(X,Y)$ is Gumbel with scale $\sigma$ and location $\beta$, for some function $f$ (such as $X+Y$ for example)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X,Y$ have some joint distribution, such that some $Z=t(X,Y)$ has a known (fully specified) continuous distribution. Let $F_Z$ be the cdf of $Z$. Let  $G_0$ be the cdf of a standard Gumbel.

Then $f_{0}(X,Y) = G_0^{-1}(F_Z(t(X,Y)))$ has a standard Gumbel distribution. Any other Gumbel may be obtained by considering $f_{\alpha,\tau}(X,Y) = \alpha+\tau G_0^{-1}(F_Z(t(X,Y)))$.

Thus we can construct any number of examples with ease.

For example, let $X$ and $Y$ be independent standard normals, let $\Phi$ be the standard normal cdf. Then $G_0^{-1}(\Phi(\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}}))$ will be standard Gumbel.

Note that $G_0^{-1}(u) = -\log(-\log(u))$ is very simple in form.

Let us simulate, so you can see it in action:

```
 n <- 1000000L
 x <- rnorm(n)
 y <- rnorm(n)
 v <- -log(-log(pnorm((x+y)/sqrt(2))))
 hist(v,n=100,freq=FALSE)
 curve(exp(-(x+exp(-x))),-3,10,col=4,add=TRUE)
```

[image: histogram of simulated values with overlaid standard Gumbel cdf]

Another example would be to take $X,Y$ to be independent standard uniform, and let $Z=\max(X,Y)^2$, then $V=-\log(-\log(Z))$ will again be standard Gumbel.

```
 n=1000000L
 hist(-log(-log(pmax(runif(n),runif(n))^2)),n=100,freq=FALSE)
 curve(exp(-(x+exp(-x))),-3,10,col=4,add=TRUE)
```

(I won't include the plot this time, it looks the same as before).

... and so forth. You could construct a hundred examples in an afternoon, were you so inclined.